# What's the "elevator pitch" for our site?

Tags: discussion

First off, I want to congratulate our community for reaching another milestone: **earlier this week, we passed the 500-question mark**. Give yourselves a round of applause—or, if you prefer a more "engineered" reward, perhaps a nice set of [neodymium ball-bearings](https://www.google.com/search?q=neodymium%20magnet%20balls&tbm=isch)?

Whatever your choice of reward, this weekend let's give some thought to question #5 in Robert's list of [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/):

> #### 5. What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?
>
> Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger.
> You have precisely one floor to describe your community to them. What
> would you say? The elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes
> what your site is about. Every word counts!
>
> Once decided, it can be sliced and diced to form:
>
> - the tagline
> - the motto
> - the blurb under the logo
> - a convenience redirect “nickname” for the site
> - perhaps eventually the domain name in some form
>
> (Due to a variety of practical difficulties with domain names, we
> prefer to de-emphasize domain name selection. Most sites will retain
> their `topic.stackexchange.com` names indefinitely.)
>
> Naming is hard — really hard. But if you can come up with a sensible
> elevator pitch for your community, it’s a great starting point.

Please limit yourself to one elevator pitch (or perhaps just a few slight variations on a theme) per answer, so that each idea can be addressed individually. If you have lots of ideas, it's okay to suggest more than one. And be sure to give feedback on other ideas that come in.

Answer (score 4):

On Engineering SE, you can find expert solutions to the problems encountered by engineers working at every stage of their careers—both practical questions about the engineering profession and technical questions in any subfield, from design to implementation and beyond.

Answer (score 3):

Engineering Stack Exchange is a community of problem solvers collaboratively sourcing solutions to ungoogle-able engineering challenges

Answer (score 0):

You've learned how the world works, now come here to make it work.

Comment: This one seems a bit vague. Could as easily be the motto of a site devoted to political science, business management, etc....